# How to return a expandoobject in web api

Tags: json, dynamic, asp.net-web-api, javascriptserializer, expandoobject

I have a action, the code is as follows:

```
public class BookController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/book/5
    public object Get(int id)
    {
        using (System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader = this.ExecuteReader("SELECT BookId, BookName FROM Book WHERE BookId=1"))
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    obj[reader.GetName(i)] = reader.GetValue(i);
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

and i got this:

[{"Key":"BookId","Value":1},{"Key":"BookName", "Value":"my boook"}]

but this is not what i wanted, i want this:
{"BookId":1, "BookName":"my book"}

what shoud i do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/) to serialize the `ExpandoObject` viz. `Dictionary`. It will not include the Key and Value rather you'll get the Key->data, value -> data. Before returning the object serialize it then return.

e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, int> points = new Dictionary<string, int>
 {
     { "James", 9001 },
     { "Jo", 3474 },
     { "Jess", 11926 }
 };

 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(points, Formatting.Indented);
```

Ouput:

```
{
 "James": 9001,
 "Jo": 3474,
 "Jess": 11926
}
```

In you method it would look like:

```
 // GET api/book/5
    public object Get(int id)
    {
        using (System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader = this.ExecuteReader("SELECT BookId, BookName FROM Book WHERE BookId=1"))
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    obj[reader.GetName(i)] = reader.GetValue(i);
                }
            }
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but i got a json string, not json object...i have to parse it on client side.(android app, ios app)

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` returns string. Since your method had return type object it will automatically upcast to object. Change your return type in method signature and it will work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

In Web API 2, the code given in the question :

```cs
// GET api/book/5
public object Get(int id)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    obj["BookId"] = 1;
    obj["BookName"] = "my book";
    return obj;
}
```

works as expected when serializing as JSON ( `{"BookId":1,"BookName":"my book"}` ), but throws an Exception with XML serialization.

Use this instead :

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    obj["BookId"] = 1;
    obj["BookName"] = "my book";
    return Ok(obj);
}
```